# Is there any good resources on WebService?

Tags: web-services

The webservice on MSDN is now all about the Windows Communication Foundation. Is there any site out there that deal with WebService only? (.Net)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did find this section for web services under [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950421.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.xml.com/